# object field import in scala

Tags: scala, object, import

I have a very simple question of style. 
What is the best way to access a field or a method defined in an object ? 
For example if I have an object `Foo` that define a field `bar`, would you rather do `import Foob.bar` and then refer to it in the scope as `bar` or call Foo.bar wherever you need the field. From what I have read in most libraries, Foo.bar seems the standard way to do it but I would like to be sure.

Thanks,

Comment: There is no best way if it is a matter of style, since style is always subjective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, usually `Foo.bar` is used, but that depends on the coder community behind the project as Frank pinted out.

If you would like to use all members without having to prefix it with `Foo`, you can do that too:

```
object Foo {
  val x = "..."
}

class Foo {
  import Foo._
  println(x)
}
```